# How to print a string representation of myFirstCar using the _str_method?

Tags: python

I'm doing this question in a python book and I just stumbled across this question. As shown in the title I wrote above, it's asking me to use that variable with the _str_method and also, I should get the output: 
`Make = Honda, Model = Civic, Color = White, Price = 1500` 
How should I write the code? (Please help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add some context to what has been said by others: the `__str__` method on a class is used auto-magically when asking for the string representation of an object (either implicitly, or explicitly via `str(myObject)`). This method determines what gets produced as the string representation. So you'll want a class (myFirstCar), and you'll want to give it a `__str__` method that outputs what you want (`Make = Honda, Model = Civic, Color = White, Price = 1500`). Here's some code that achieves that:

```
class myFirstCar:
    def __init__(self, make, model, color, price):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Make = {self.make}, Model = {self.model}, Color = {self.color}, Price = {self.price}'

>> print(str(myFirstCar('Honda', 'Civic', 'White', '1500')))
Make = Honda, Model = Civic, Color = White, Price = 1500
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Great! Thanks for selecting it as the correct answer, feel free to upvote as well if possible!

Answer (score 0):

```
class myFirstCar:
    def __init__(self, make, model, color, price):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.color = color
        self.price = price

    def __str__():
        s = 'Make = ' + self.make + ', Model = ' + self.model + ', Color = ' + self.color + ', Price = ' + self.Price
        return s
```

Instantiate your class and call the `__str__` method.

Comment: self.price instead of self.Price

Answer (score 0):

`classes` will be your friend here.

```
class Car:
  def __init__(self, make, model, color, price):
    self.make = make
    self.model = model
    self.color = color
    self.price = price

car = Car('Honda', 'Civic', 'White', '1500')
print('Make = ' + car.make + ', Model = ' + car.model + ', Color = ' + car.color + ', Price = ' + car.price)
```

On top of this, you can make other variables to store the attributes of whatever other car you want to create. Such as:

`car2 = Car('Toyota', 'Camry', 'Black', '1900')`

And you would call it the same way.